# I Cant Seem to get it too join the voice channel discord.py

Tags: python, discord

```
import discord
import random

client = discord.Client()


async def joinVoiceChannel():


    channel = client.get_channel('Id')
    voice =  client.join_voice_channel(channel)
    print('Bot should joined the Channel')


 @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        #info
        print('Logged in as')
        print(client.user.name)
        print(client.user.id)
        print('------')
        await joinVoiceChannel()


client.run('token')
```

I dont know why it doesnt work , please help, I have looked at things but nothing seems to work. I have searched everything
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

```
import discord
import random

client = discord.Client()

@Client.event
async def on_ready():
    #info
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

    channel = Client.get_channel('id')
    await Client.join_voice_channel(channel)
    print('Bot should joined the Channel')

client.run('token')
```

Also ensure that you have PyNaCl installed, can install it from your command line by copying and pasting `py -m pip install PyNaCl`